# Proof: $x (y - x + 1) > y$ if $y > x$

Tags: proof-writing

I'm working on a computation which depends on the idea that given two natural numbers $x$ and $y$ where $y > x$, the product $x(y - x)$ will always be greater than $y$.

Is there a proof of this ? My elementary math is a bit rusty.

The simple evaluation gives : $xy - x^2$

I can't seem to formalize this relation with respect to $y$. Could somebody give me a refresher on the proof strategies for such a problem ?

**EDIT: **
Apologies. I got lost in writing it here. It's actually $x (y - x + 1)$. So basically given two numbers this would result in the value above plus a summation series that is solvable using $x(x+1)/2$. Does that make more sense ?
(P.S: thank you for the quick response.)

Comment: Let $y = 2$ and $x = 1$. Then $y > x$, but $x (y - x) = 1 \cdot (2-1) = 1$ and $y = 2$. Your statement is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$x(y-x+1)>y\iff xy-y>x(x-1)$$
$$\iff y(x-1)>x(x-1)\iff (y-x)(x-1)>0$$

which will be true if $(y>x$ and $x>1)$ or if $(y<x$ and $x<1)$

i.e.,  if $y>x>1$ or $y<x<1$

Comment: Yippee... I just saved a variable cause of this. Thanks.

Comment: @SaadFarooq, my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

Try $y=x+1$, then the product is $x$, which is not greater than $y$. Hence you try to prove something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try $x=2$ and $y=3$. Then $x(y-x)=2<y$.

Answer (score 1):

A different way to look at the problem:
$$x(y-x+1)=-x^2+(y+1)x$$
with fixed $y$ is a quadratic function in $x$. The coefficient by $x^2$ is negative, so the maximal value of it will be at $x=\frac{y+1}{2}$, which is smaller than $y$ if $y>1$, and the value is equal to $\frac{(y+1)^2}{4}$, which is clearly larger than $y$ for $y\geq 3$, for example.